# programa factorial

Tags: python, factorial

Hola estoy intentando a hacer el siguiente programa, a ver si me pueden ayudar a resolverlo. lo he intentado pero no logro dar con el.

Programa que busca 3 factoriales a!, b! y c! tal que sumados de como resultado el numero que el usuario va a ingresar. a, b y c son únicos, no se repiten y están dentro de un rango de 1 a 8.

Es posible que el numero que ingrese no exista en la solución.

Ej:
150= 5! 4! y 3!

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que haz intentado? Así se te puede ayudar con mayor facilidad y precisión. También te sugiero que leas el recorrido (https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para obtener mayor ayuda a tus preguntas.

Comment: Parece evidente que esta pregunta es en el fondo el enunciado de una tarea que te han pedido. Preguntar en un sitio como este por una solución a tu tarea sin mostrar lo que has intentado y _sin especificar qué conocimientos tienes_, no sólo está mal visto, sino que además es bastante inútil para ti. Lo más probable es que las respuestas que obtengas usen características avanzadas del leguaje que aún no hayais estudiado, por lo que sólo servirán para que tu profesor descubra que en realidad no lo has hecho tú.

Answer (score 1):

Como necesitaremos la lista de factoriales del `1!` al `9!`, lo mejor es crear los 9 valores:

```py
acc = 1
facts = [acc:=acc*i for i in range(1,10)]
```

También podríamos crear un diccionario con todas las posibles combinaciones de estos 9 números, sólo son 165 combinaciones posibles:

```py
suma_3_facts = {i+j+k: (i,j,k)
                for i in facts
                for j in facts
                for k in facts
                if i>=j>=k}
```

Y finalmente, el código para probar si existe una combinación:

```py
n = 150

if n in suma_3_facts:
    (a,b,c) = suma_3_facts[n]
    print(f"{n} es la suma de {a} + {b} + {c}")
else:
    print(f"{n} no se puede expresar como suma de factoriales")
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
entr = int(input())
fact = [int(0) for i in range(9)]

fact[0] = 1
for i in range(1, 9):
    fact[i] = fact[i - 1] * i
for a in range(1, 9):
    for b in range(a, 9):
        for c in range(b, 9):
            if(fact[a] + fact[b] + fact[c] == entr):
                print(str(a) + " " + str(b) + " " + str(c))
                exit(0)

print("No existe")
```